# Combining JQuery and AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Based on the AngularJS document

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

It says

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

Does this means that we can go ahead and include JQuery JS files use the JQuery selectors like **angular.element("body").css({})** and use the functions?

I tested that it is working fine, but I want to know

Is there any official document/wiki which recommends/not-recommends the combination of AngularJS+JQuery

Did anyone faced a big performance issue when combining this two?

Comment: It's not that you'll face problems but instead of using `AngularJS approach` you'll use `jQuery`

Comment: I would say, if you do need full blown jquery the jqLite is better as you do not need to include additional lib loaded to your page. As to performance, it depends how you write it and what functionality and how you are using it.

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS is great for that. It actually runs on its side and does not interfere with other libraries. You are right, you can use `angular.element("body").css({})` and you are actually using jQuery just as you would with `$`.

The performance will be the jQuery performance hit. So it depends how you use it. There is no performance hit in the combining of the two.

I almost always use the two together and it's a breeze.

You should definitely try to do things the angular way when possible though. Do not use `.on('click')` but ng-click, etc... You should not have to use more than what jQlite and Angular is offering in most cases if you do things right.

Answer (score 0):

JqLite is a subset of the jquery functions. You have use jQuery if you wanna do DOM manipulation or use modules as **angular-bootstrap**.