# Should I use Angular Material or Bootstrap Material for my Angular 6 app?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, bootstrap-material-design

I decided to create a new Angular 6 application with Material Design.
The question is what material library to use?

- Angular Material (https://material.angular.io/)
- Material Design for Bootstrap (https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/)

As I see other Bootstrap Material library has their own version for Angular to **avoid using JQuery**. (https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/)

Why do you need to avoid it? Is it buggy or just hard for development?

MDBootstrap for Angular has free and payed version. I didnt like the free version and cannot use the payed one.

Should I really use Material Design for Bootstrap with JQuery in my new Angular app?

Comment: this is not coding related question

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow :) The Stackoverflow platform is not designed for opinion based questions. You can use whatever you want. I personally like Angular Material and the angular flex-layout.

Comment: but it is a very good question nowdays

Comment: the question is more about what problem do I face using JQuery in Angular app?

Comment: Asking such a specific question is fine. You can create a new question for that. The problem you will face is that JQuery goes around Angular model update cycle stuff.

Comment: You can choose whatever you like. my choice is Angular material. Well it's not an good idea to use both. More detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707577/is-that-a-good-practice-to-use-jquery-with-angularjs

Comment: Angular Material is made by Google, as well as Angular and Material Design. Choosing it was pretty easy ^^

Comment: Is about your preference, maybe the best option is going for the one you are more experienced with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting question, but I think it is above all a matter of taste and personal use.

I consider Bootstrap is modern and Material is elegant, but those are my personal view.

As for use, I find Bootstrap more easily customizable and complete.

I also point out other libraries more or less similar, I got along well with NgBootstrap for Angular:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Nebular: https://akveo.github.io/nebular/

Comment: Nebular looks very pretty!

Comment: ng-bootstrap it's a replacement to jquery bootstrap components, not a standalone bootstrap kit: it is needed to use bootstrap css anyway in an angular way. ngx-bootrap is it's clone.

Answer (score 15):

If you are going to use Angular, definitely Angular Material.  When it started it was the Material Design implementation for Angular.  As of Angular 6, the Angular team have integrated it into the release train for Angular.

You will find the release notes for Angular talk about new features in core along wither Angular Material.  Angular Material is also integrated into the Angular CLI to make it even easier to use and to upgrade (ng update).  Additionally, when you look for examples, you will find many more Angular Material tutorials and resources than Material Design for Bootstrap.

When I started using it over a year and a half ago, it was just another project.  Today, I wouldn't go with any other framework since it's so integrated.

Answer (score 8):

Angular Material together with flex layout - is a very good choice.

- it works very well together with Angular-6
- no cost - MIT License
- many free icons (without troubles to integrate it)
- very good documentation
- great community

I have tried it with bootstrap too - that works, but I had had some troubles to integrate it together.

Comment: angular material, being material, is strongly opinionated as deign styleguide. If you need something more "vanilla" on top of wich you can apply your own style guide, use just the behavior and patterns of material: that's the job of angular CDK. I.e., cdk-table is the same mat-table component _without any style_. So you can use only the cdk drag & drop version without the material overhead, and on top of this apply bs4, tailwind, bulma, youNameIt css to have *your* style

Answer (score 3):

Angular does not need jquery in any way and jquery itself creates a lot of architectural problems, breaking the ecosystem. The fact that bs need jquery for its more complex components is an issue who creates unuseful hoverhead in an angular app, wich will be hopefully jquery-free. If you use vanilla bootstrap for your angular project, you have to include only the css to avoid using jquery, stating that any behaviour jquery bootsrap components give you could, and had to, be replicated easily with a corresponding angular component. ngx_bootstrap and other projects do an excellent job in supply regular angular components that replaces jquery version.