# How can I inject to an html page in assets a component?(Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a component named `center-info` and another component named `slideshow`.
I inject to the `center-info`, html pages, that i stored in assets, with the help of the following code:
`center-info.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-center-info',
  templateUrl: './center-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./center-info.component.css']
})
export class CenterInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  public centerId = "";
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      let id = params.get('id');
      this.centerId = id;
    });
    $("#center-info").load(`assets/centers/${this.centerId}.html`);
  }
}
```

I can see the text I wrote in the html pages in assets, but when I try to call a component from one of the html pages in the asset, The component does not appear on the screen.
One of the html pages in assets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/centers/centers.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="center-info">
    <p>this is html page in assets</p>

    <app-slideshow ></app-slideshow>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the `<app-slideshow ></app-slideshow>` appear on the screen?
Thanks so much to all the helpers!

Comment: Not a good idea to use JQuery in angular application: read this: [is-that-a-good-practice-to-use-jquery-with-angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707577/is-that-a-good-practice-to-use-jquery-with-angularjs)

Comment: Assets can use a url, so why not try an iframe with the src set to a url?

Comment: @JohnPeters, Thank you for your answer! But how can a component be represented in url?

Comment: Use a route. Routes tie URLs to components.  Except for assets, they are statically always there. No Route route needed.